# Keep alpha-transparency of a video through HDMI

Tags: opengl, gpu, video-processing, alpha-transparency, hdmi

The scenario I'm dealing with is actually as follow: I need to get the screen generated by OpenGL and send it through HDMI to a FPGA component while keeping the alpha channel. But right now the data that is being sent through HDMI is only RGB (24bit without alpha channel) So i need a way to force sending the Alpha bits through this port somehow.

See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck94V.jpg

One solution i could think of is to convert the screen buffer from RGBA mode to RGB while mixing the Alpha channels within the RGB buffer.

For example:

```
The original buffer: [R G B A][R G B A][R G B A]
The output i want: [R G B][A R G][B A R][G B A]
```

The point is not having to go through every single pixels.
But I'm not sure if it's possible at all using OpenGL or any technology (VideoCore kernel?)

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? What about determining why your Alpha channel is not being passed through your HDMI link? You need HDMI spec 1.3+ to support > 24bit colour.

Comment: @kevinf, I am currently working on a project that could use this. Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: @PaulKnopf I went another direction with the project. I still wish to learn more about Alpha channel in the video processing path though.

Answer (score 1):

> opengl frame buffer

Do you actually mean a *[framebuffer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer)*, or some kind of texture? Because framebuffers cannot be resized, and the size of this resulting image will be *larger* in the number of pixels by 25%. You can't actually do that.

You could do it with a texture, but only by resizing it. You would have to get the texel data with `glGetTexImage` into some buffer, then upload the texel data to another texture with `glTexImage2D`. You would simply change the [pixel transfer format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_format) and texture width appropriately. The read would use `GL_RGBA`, and the write would use `GL_RGB`, with an internal format of `GL_RGB8`.

The *performance* of this will almost certainly not be very good. But it should *work*.

But no, there is no simple call you can make to cause this to happen.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The scenario I'm dealing with is actually as follow:
I need to get the screen generated by OpenGL and send it through HDMI to a FPGA component while keeping the alpha channel. But right now the data that is being sent through HDMI is only RGB (24bit without alpha channel) So i need a way to force sending the Alpha bits through this port somehow. Do you have any suggestion? Is there anyway to get the Alpha Buffer (like the Stencil buffer)?

Thanks

Comment: @AkitoEki: If all of that is relevant, you should put it in your question. And there's no such thing as an "alpha buffer". Colors are simply composed of up to four separate channels, one of which is alpha.

Comment: Thanks Nicol, I'll update my question with some pictures too. :)

Comment: I've finished updating the question with explanation of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @AkitoEki, I am attempting to do the same exact thing at this moment. I could really use your help/experience with this. Can you e-mail me at theonlylawislove@gmail.com? I'd be willing to pay for consulting if you have anything that can help me. Have you used Qt?

Comment: @PaulKnopf Hey Paul, Sorry I missed your questions, do you still need help on this?

Comment: @AkitoEki, yes, I still could use some help. Are you available for some consulting work?'

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to send the alpha channel separately in opengl via different rgb or hdmi video output on your video card.
So your pc now outputs RGB down one cable, and then the Alpha down the other cable. Your alpha probably needs to be converted to grey scale so that it is still 24 bits.
You then select the which signal is the key in your fpga. 
I'm presuming your fpga supports chroma key.

I have done something similar before but using a program called Brainstorm which uses a specific video card that supports SDI out and it splits the RGB, and the Alpha into separate video channels(cables), and then the vision mixer does the keying.

Today, however, I have created a new solution which mixes the multiple video channels first on the pc, and then outputs the final mixed video directly to either a RTMP streaming server or to a DVI to SDI scan converter.