# Linux framebuffers with ARGB32. Alpha? How does a framebuffer support Alpha?

Tags: linux, qt, fpga, framebuffer, alphablending

After looking at the source for Qt, it seems that it, and framebuffers in general, [support alpha transparency](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/dev/src/plugins/platforms/linuxfb/qlinuxfbscreen.cpp#L167).

```
static QImage::Format determineFormat(const fb_var_screeninfo &info, int depth)
{
    const fb_bitfield rgba[4] = { info.red, info.green,
                                  info.blue, info.transp };

    QImage::Format format = QImage::Format_Invalid;

    switch (depth) {
    case 32: {
        const fb_bitfield argb8888[4] = {{16, 8, 0}, {8, 8, 0},
                                         {0, 8, 0}, {24, 8, 0}};
        const fb_bitfield abgr8888[4] = {{0, 8, 0}, {8, 8, 0},
                                         {16, 8, 0}, {24, 8, 0}};
        if (memcmp(rgba, argb8888, 4 * sizeof(fb_bitfield)) == 0) {
            format = QImage::Format_ARGB32;
        } else if (memcmp(rgba, argb8888, 3 * sizeof(fb_bitfield)) == 0) {
            format = QImage::Format_RGB32;
        } else if (memcmp(rgba, abgr8888, 3 * sizeof(fb_bitfield)) == 0) {
            format = QImage::Format_RGB32;
            // pixeltype = BGRPixel;
        }
        break;
    }
    // code ommited
}
```

What does it mean if a framebuffer supports alpha? Don't framebuffers typically represent monitors?

I am investigating the possibility of sending the alpha channel out HDMI for video overlay on an FPGA chip, [similar to this users question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144540/keep-alpha-transparency-of-a-video-through-hdmi).

I am wondering that if I have an external monitor, that some hows registers itself within linux to have a depth of 32bits with an alpha channel, with this get sent out the HDMI?

Comment: A framebuffer is just a place where you draw raster graphics in memory.  That's all it is.  You can make as many framebuffers as you like, and do whatever you want with them.

Answer (score 3):

The alpha component is *not* transmitted to the monitor.  But,

- Alpha might be used by the compositor, allowing a window on screen to be transparent.  For example, you can use the alpha channel in a WebGL framebuffer to show the document underneath the WebGL canvas.
- You might use the alpha component in your application, even if the compositor doesn't use it.
- It is more convenient to waste a byte of memory per pixel than it is to have an odd-sized pixel.  Hardware framebuffers support a variety of 1, 2, and 4-channel formats, but only a few 3-channel formats.

The HDMI cable itself can carry a small variety of different video formats, such as RGB and YCbCr, with variations in subsampling and bit depth.  The advantage to even-sized pixel formats does not apply to streamed data.